# NUnit/Selenium/C# test gives "System.Exception : The test case source could not be found." error

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Getting error message from the title above. Test itself does not get to this line >> `public void IdentityTenantCreation(AccountInfo acct)`. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Otherwards does not go into LoginData class at all.

```
public class AccountInfo
{
    public string REGION { get; set; }
    public string USER { get; set; }
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
    public string ACCTNAME { get; set; }
    public string ACCTCONTACT { get; set; }
}

public class LoginData
{
    public static IEnumerable<AccountInfo> GetLoginData
    {
        get
        {
            AccountInfo acctInformation = new();
            var dataSheet = ExcelHelpers.ReadDataSheet("Login");
            foreach (var keys in dataSheet[0].Keys)
            {
                string flag = dataSheet[0][keys][1].colValue;
                if (flag[0].ToString().ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    acctInformation = new()
                    {
                        REGION = dataSheet[0][keys][0].colValue,
                        USER = dataSheet[0][keys][2].colValue,
                        PASSWORD = dataSheet[0][keys][3].colValue,
                        ACCTNAME = dataSheet[0][keys][4].colValue,
                        ACCTCONTACT = dataSheet[0][keys][5].colValue
                    };
                }
            }
            yield return acctInformation;
        }
    }
} 


    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(LoginData), "GetData")]
        public void IdentityTenantCreation(AccountInfo acct) 
    {
        LogIntoSF(acct.USER, acct.PASSWORD);
        SwitchToClassicDash();

       .......
    }
```

Comment: There is no method, field or property in your post named "GetData". That's what cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake by me.